# Changing row grid color based on returned function value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, dwr, extjs-grid

Can you help me in changing the grid row style (bold/thin) depending on value
returned from java function.

it is only this callback function which i use, it simply check if there is record inside
one table and return true/false.

I tried the following but did not work. I always got thin style.

```
    this.getView().getRowClass =function(record, index, rowParams, store){
      Service.isInsideTable(record.data.x, function(ok){            
        if (ok){
          return 'grid-row-opened';
        }else {
          return 'grid-row-new';
        }
      });               
    }

public boolean isInsideTable(String documentId,int contId){       
          boolean ok = false;
          DBUtil dbUtil = null;
          try { 
              dbUtil = new DBUtil("mydb");
              ResultSet res=null;
              String sql ="SELECT * FROM CIRCULAR_PER_USER WHERE DOCUMENT_ID ='"+documentId+"' and CONTACT_ID="+contId;
              res=dbUtil.execQuery(sql);
              //ok = true;
              if (res.next()) ok=true;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          { 
              e.printStackTrace(); 
          }
          finally {
              if (dbUtil !=null){
                  dbUtil.close();
              }
          } 
          return ok; 
      }
```

Comment: the code sounds good, Is the callback `OK` always the same? if its always the same, then it might be your method `isInsideTable()` is not set up the right way...

Comment: my callback function simply return true or false..

Comment: please add the code of your function Service.isInsideTable

Comment: This is not a good way to do it. That means an ajax request every time the row renders. Don't do it this way, send the status back as part of the record data.

Comment: you are right Evan, but let us say iam under pressure to finish task and any update on tables lead me to changes in many areas